# how can I write to an array in a loop?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm relatively new to VBA

I think the error is in my syntax.

Bellow is a sub routine im working on. the array "MyArray" is always empty. I've dim'd and redim'd and changed the type and the syntax based on what I've seen online a million times its either always 0 or empty. please help.

```
Sub CostPerTon()

Dim FeedType As String, count#, CostPerTon#

FeedType = "Duck - Comercial - Starter - 1 to 25 Days"

Sheets("Formulations").Activate

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

i = 1

Dim IngredientCost As Double
Dim MyArray(100) As Variant


Do While i < count + 1

    IngredientCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FeedType, Range("1:1048576"), i + 2, 0) _
     * Worksheets("Costs").Cells(i + 2, 2) * (1 / 1000)
    MyArray(i) = IngredientCost

    i = i + 1


Loop


End Sub
```

the variable "IngredientCost" has values when I cycle through the loop so that function is fine. It breaks down at the MyArray(i)=IngredientCost line. it just stays empty

and the count is 14

Comment: Stop your code right after `count = Application.....` and tell us what the variable `count` holds at that time.

Comment: Your code probably stumbles over the definition `Range("1:1048576")` in the VLOOKUP function. The address of that range, *$1:$1048576*, isn't a valid range for VLOOKUP. Rather than throwing an error VBA just stops code execution at that point and probably goes to the next loop or even exits altogether. Either way your array remains empty.

Comment: @JvdV the count is 14

Comment: @Variatus the variable "IngredientCost" has values when I cycle through the loop so that function is fine. It breaks down at the MyArray(i)=IngredientCost line. it just stays empty

Comment: It stays empty because `IngredientCost` is empty or holds a value that can't be processed at that point. `IngredientCost` is in that condition because its calculation is flawed. The flaw consists of a faulty VLookup. The fault of the VLookup is in that its range consists of a single column. The range doesn't have any column `i + 2`.  So, the question isn't why it doesn't work but why it doesn't throw an error. Look for the answer in VBA's relationship with the worksheet function. Try the worksheet function, as defined in your code, on a worksheet. Break up components of `IngredientCost`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, which column do you want return in VLookup function:

```
IngredientCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FeedType, Range("1:1048576"), i + 2, 0) _
 * Worksheets("Costs").Cells(i + 2, 2) * (1 / 1000)
```

last parameter function you defined:

```
i + 2
```

so if you find **"Duck - Comercial - Starter - 1 to 25 Days"** e.g in 25. row:
--> i=25 and Vlookup want to return 27th column which is empty probably.

Consider that:

```
IngredientCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FeedType, Range("1:1048576"),3, 0) _
 * Worksheets("Costs").Cells(i + 2, 2) * (1 / 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but the variable "IngredientCost" has values when I cycle through the loop so that function is fine. It breaks down at the MyArray(i)=IngredientCost line. it just stays empty